# require works but import does not work in node js version 14+

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, deployment, hosting

everything works very fine in the localhost with the node 14.

But when i try to host it to the cpanel using es6 import, it fails and gives the error like,

```
RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory
    at internal/deps/cjs-module-lexer/dist/lexer.js:1:33272
    at async initCJSParse (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:67:5)
    at async Loader.commonjsStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:181:18)
```

It is very weird.

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "practice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type":"module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "run": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

index.js file

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World test2");
});

app.listen();
```

debug log
[image]
need some help hosting my nodejs app to cpanel

Comment: what happens if you try `"run": "node --experimental-modules index.js"` in your `scripts`?

Comment: Try `const express = require('express');` instead.

Comment: same thing happen @AlanOmar, however in the localhost everything works fine. It  happens only when i am hosting to the cpanel

Comment: @admi I have import es6 in my whole big project. And i wanna continue on that. I tried the require and it does work but then i have to change everything on my app. ANd that would be 1000s of line

Comment: @AmanChaudhary find any solutions?